ADO Flaky test integration for jest UI tests
I am trying to use ADO flaky test management feature. Looking at the documentation it seems for jest test cases, we have to use custom detection. I understand we have to use REST api to update flakiness. But, I am not sure how to identify flaky test in jest and at what point to make the call.
Any input on that and any sample code will be helpful.

Flaky tests, no matter the language, they are tests that produce different results each time they are run, even when the code being tested has not changed.
The Test Results, Result Meta Data - Update REST API mentioned in the doc for Custom detection is used to update properties of test result meta data, it won't change the test result, but can add or delete flaky flag on the test.

Unlike the Flaky UI button, rest api won't add flag or remove flag on UI, but when you try to set flaky flag on the test, it will report it's already marked. The flag will appear in subsequent test run.

For flaky test in jest, it's recommended to check doc How to Manage Flaky Tests in Jest which contains some samples.
Below is an example of a flaky test due to a race condition from doc:
test("flaky test due to race condition", () => {
  let value = 0;
  asyncOperation().then(() => (value = 1));
  expect(value).toBe(1); // May fail if asyncOperation hasn't completed
});

Hope it helps.
